# How to create sub site in wordpress multisite programmatically?

Tags: multisite

I have wordpress multisite created. Now I want to create a 10 sub sites automatic/programmatically. I have created one form and that form is uploaded on the same server. So once the user filled out that form and the subsite needs to be create automatic. If you have any article, plugin, code or script please help me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: try this https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpmu_create_blog

Answer (score 1):

With `wpmu_create_blog()` function, we can create subsites easily.

Add the following code in your form submit

```
wpmu_create_blog ( 'your_domain', '/subsite_path',  'Title of Subsite', '1' );
```

NB: if your site url is https://www.example.com then **your_domain** is should be **example.com**

Ref: https://www.krishaweb.com/how-to-programmatically-create-new-site-in-wordpress-multisite-within-60-minutes/

Comment: Can this explanation be expanded upon? How do you implement this in wordpress?

Comment: @Mr.Meeseeks I converted your answer into a comment (don't leave replies as comments you'll get marked as a spambot and banned). This is an old answer and it was never marked as correct. Also the explanation as as precise as it needs to be to answer the question, what you're hoping for will need more context than this question or answer can provide. You should ask a new question and explain what you're trying to do in greater detail